# Open link from csv using python, issue with invalid characters for a URL

Tags: python

This is the code I have, it works for the most part, it opens the url but the url contains '' which is invalid when trying to open a link. how do I remove these before using webbrowser.open?

```
import time, csv, webbrowser


wait_time = 30

with open(r'C:\Users\Documents\list_of_url.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        list2 = str(row).strip('[]')
        webbrowser.open(list2,new = 0, autoraise = True)

        time.sleep(wait_time)
```

example urls from csv
    https://1178/cr_1178_1.tif
    https://1179/cr_1179_1.tif
    https://1180/cr_1180_1.tif

Problem:
This is what the url that it tries to open looks like, there are invalid characters ('') that a browser doesn't allow
'https//1178/cr_1178_1.tif'

SOLVED:

```
import time, csv, webbrowser


wait_time = 5

with open(r'D:\Book3.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        webbrowser.open(row[0], new = 0, autoraise = True)
        print(row)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your code example because of missing file. Have you tried 
`list2.replace("'",'')` ?

Comment: Why `list2 = str(row).strip('[]')`? `row` is a python list, and you'd typically grab one of its items. Is the url in one of the columns? If its say, column 1, you'd get the url by `row[1]`. Instead of the example urls you've posted which make no sense, can you put a print in the for loop (`print(row)`) and show us a few lines of its output?

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for your help. Here is the output. Clearly the web browser won't open a page with quotes at the start or end. 

['www.google.com']
['www.amazon.com']
['www.facebook.com']

Comment: Is that one single print or are you putting several together? `['www.google.com']` is python's way of printing a list with one string item. In that case you just want to do `webbrowser.open(row[0], new = 0, autoraise = True)`

Comment: @tdelaney, solved thank you. I will brush up on my python lists for the future, cheers

Comment: Answers dont get [edit]et in - post an answer and remove it from the question. Then you can self-accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

import time, csv, webbrowser

```
wait_time = 5

with open(r'D:\Book3.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        webbrowser.open(row[0], new = 0, autoraise = True)
        print(row)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
```